# Jenkins error: FATAL: null -- java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, jenkins

Jenkins sometimes reports an error and sometimes my build goes perfect:

Error:

FATAL: null

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.run(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:137)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.calcChangeLog(SubversionSCM.java:730)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:865)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1276)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:560)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:485)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
```

Any idea how to resolve the issue?

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29724

Answer (score 0):

High probably the issue is solved. At the SVN-update some folder can't be found on the repo-anymore. After deleting these folders it seem to be solved.